# Trying to figure if blockchain has finished downloading.

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mastering-ethereum

I am working on the text, Mastering Ethereum and working on the part where one has to download the blockchain. Now I elected to use geth because parity seemed to be getting stuck on blocks for almost an entire night.

Anyways, I have been doing the download using geth and I believe I am on the right path , the age of blocks started off from over 2 years and now it's down to under a minutes. Now looking at my console if all transactions are less than a minute old.

1) Is it safe to say I have finished downloading the block chain?

2) Can I close this page and when I want to continue or update just run the geth.exe again?

3) If i am not finished, and I close this page, will running the geth.exe resume where i left off?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check is to do the following:

- in a separate terminal, run `geth attach` to attach to your node
- type `eth.syncing` to check the status. If it returns `false` then you are synced. If not, it gives you information about the sync.

You *can* close the page, but you would stop syncing. When you ran `geth.exe`, it will pick up right where it left off.